# Get value from string in specific place

Tags: t-sql, charindex

I'm using T-SQL language and I'm wondering the best way to get specific information from a string.

Example of string :

> Category : azd Nom du fichier : 684157 Type de doc : info Id : 21542

The idea is to get the value "684157", which will be always between "fichier :" and "Type".

I have tried with `substring` and `charindex` but I miss something.

Here is my code

```
select substring(com, charindex('fichier : ', com)+len('fichier : '), charindex('Type', com)-charindex('fichier : ', com) + len('Type')) 
from myTable
```

Comment: Use charindex to find "fichier :" and "Type :" and then substring between the 2 of them

Comment: Of course, the best way would be to not put yourself it this situation to begin with. Don't store data like that in your database. Either use well-known string formats such as json or xml, or simply store each data point in it's own column (which is the best option when it comes to relational databases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a neater way of doing this but here's a method using `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(com,  
    CHARINDEX('fichier :', com) + LEN('fichier :'), -- start index
    CHARINDEX('Type :', com) - (CHARINDEX('fichier :', com) + LEN('fichier :'))) -- length
FROM MyTable
```

The `startIndex` is the index of `fichier :` plus the length of `fichier :`.  The end index is the index of `Type :`.  For `SUBSTRING` we need to use the start index and the length.  To calculate the length of the substring we use the index of `Type :` and subtract what we calculated for `startIndex`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would do:

```
SELECT LEFT(S.CutString,CHARINDEX(' Type :',S.CutString)) AS FinalString
FROM (VALUES('Category : azd Nom du fichier : 684157 Type : info Id : 21542'))V(String) --Would be your table
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(STUFF(V.String,1,CHARINDEX('fichier : ',V.String) + LEN('fichier : '),'')))S(CutString);
```

Answer (score 0):

additional variant:

```
SELECT parsename(replace(replace(com,'fichier : ','.'), 'Type','.'),2)
FROM MyTable
```

test:

[image]

Comment: You are assuming that the input doesn't happen to contain any occurrences of ".". The OP's broad range of sample data doesn't make that clear.

Comment: @HABO in such cases you just need to replace `.` by not used char, e.g. `|`, and after split replace back

Comment: @HABO anyway variant provided by me is just an example how to achieve required result and can be useful in some cases